# Java - Receiving a Malformed/Incomplete String From a UDP Transaction

Tags: java, c, udp

I have a Java application that I've written to communicate with a server (implemented in C) over UDP. This application exchanges all data as strings.

Java code:

```
byte[] buff = data.getBytes();

// Parse IP address
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(addr);

// Send data
DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length, address, port);
DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket();
sock.send(pack);

// Wait for a response
byte[] recvBuff = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
DatagramPacket recv = new DatagramPacket(recvBuff, BUFF_SIZE);
sock.receive(recv);

sock.close();

// Pass the data to some down-stream process
handler(new String(recvBuff, "UTF-8");
```

C code:

```
void someFunction(struct sockaddr_in client){
    srand(time(0));
    int num = rand(); // Generate some garbage data
    char* data = malloc(15);
    sprintf(data, "%d", num);
    send_udp(client, data);
}

/*
* Sends all bytes contained in buf2 over UDP
*/
int send_udp(struct sockaddr_in client, char* buf2){
    int len = sizeof(client);
    return sendto(sockfd, buf2, strlen(buf2), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, len);
}
```

When my Java code receives a string back from the C server and parses the bytes it received into a string, the string appears to be "incomplete," having no closing quotation mark when viewed from a debugger or stack trace. These strings will also cause several built-in methods to throw exceptions. For example, passing such a string containing an otherwise valid integer to Integer.parse() will cause a number format exception to be raised.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "26310
```

I have verified I am decoding the raw UDP bytes using UTF-8.

My C code is running on a 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 installation. My Java code is running on OpenJDK 1.8.0_151 through Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3).

Does anyone have an idea as to why this might be happening and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Aside: in the C code `srand(time(0));` should be called once in `main`, not in the function that calls `rand()`. If you want to use garbage values for testing, don't call `srand()` at all - then the sequence will be repeatable. You might want to use a local string, instead of dynamic memory since you have a memory leak, but this will only work if `send_udp` is synchronous.

Comment: 'I have verified that the strings have a null-terminator' strange, since sending  strlen(buf2)' does not include the NUL.

Comment: How many byte were sent? How many bytes were received? Oh, you never check `recv.getLength()`. Why is that? Don't you think that would be important information, i.e. how many bytes were actually stored in `recvBuff`? Any bytes in the buffer following received bytes are all 0's, because that's the values when the buffer is created.

Comment: @MartinJames, you're correct. The "null-terminator" was coming from excess space in the receiving buffer. Edited question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Java code didn't receive part of the string, the C code didn't send it. UDP datagrams are received intact or not at all. Or your receive buffer was too short.

The received strings cannot possibly have a null terminator.

I don't see any evidence that, or reason why, the sent strings should even have a leading quote, let alone a trailing one. I think you have misinterpreted the error message. I think the real problem is this:

```
new String(recvBuff, "UTF-8");
```

which should be

```
new String(recv.getData(), 0, recv.getLength(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I was interpreting the excess space in the receiving buffer as a "null-terminator" and incorrectly assumed that a null-terminator needed to be present when initializing the string.